# Finite Automat Machine to find binary string that contain 101

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-automata

Finite state Machine  to find binary string that contain 101 pattern anywhere 

**what i tried is**
 [image: FSM]
  [DFA TOOL](http://automatonsimulator.com/)

in the diagram above

- Start:Empty String
- S0:1
- S1:10
- S2:101

S2 is checked because its Accepting State i.e Final State

[image: FSM1]

If the input 1010000101
So my Question is will S2 go to Start State when it matches 101 for first time or will it stay on S2.Please bear me i'm learning Finite Automata and Sorry for weird diagram

Edit:**The Input in diagraph is 0 1 not 1 0**

Comment: By $101$ pattern do you mean consecutively, or there is a subword of the form $101$?
Also your machine is not deterministic, $S_2$ still requires transitions coming out of it...

Comment: The way you presented it, it looks like "Final State" is actually final. I can't think of an easy way to count the occurrences of the 101 pattern

Comment: I'm not sure whether my state diagram is right  i drew it after reading an example from here https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960222.html

Comment: @MurrayTannock  i need to find 101 pattern present in binary string it would be nice if it count occurence of 101 in binary string

Comment: Counting occurrences is not possible with a DFA, since you would require memory of some kind which DFAs do not have, Your DFA will be correct when you add the loops on $S_2$, and it enters the accept state after the first occurrence.

Comment: yes i will  add 0 and 1 loop over S2 , then its correct Finite state Diagram ?

Comment: Yes that would be correct.

Comment: @Murray Tannock thanks for Help please post it as answer i'll accept it as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add loops to your final state to ensure determinism. Then your DFA will accept on the first occurrence of $101$.